# How to watch tv or listen to radio on Meizu Pro 5?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to watch tv or listen to radio on Ubuntu Touch. I live in Denmark, and I would like to listen to e.g. DR P4, or watch live TV.
Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure about TV, but I would imagine it is possible. However, I know you can listern. To the radio fine on Ubuntu Touch. The two apps that come to mund are URadio and Local Radio (I think it is called). They can be downloaded from the Ubuntu Store. The local radio is only for UK stations though so may be URadio would be better for you in Denmark.